# Cake 3x:- how to use count and sum in find query

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

i want to select count "id" and sum of price in cakephp-3.x
simple mysql query:-

`SELECT COUNT(id) as count, SUM(price) as total_price FROM bookings WHERE id=3;`

i don't know how to write this query in cakephp-3.x

Please let me know how to write this query in cakephp-3.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try reading up on how to use the query builder of the ORM:

[Query Builder - Aggregates Group and Having](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#aggregates-group-and-having)

It will be something along these lines

```
$query = $bookings->find();
$query->select([
    'count' => $query->func()->count('id'),
    'total_price' => $query->func()->sum('price')
])->where(['id' => 3]);
```

The count will come from the number of results or by adding in the count to the query builder!

Comment: How can i fetch the data?

Comment: Its all in the docs: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html